# Python multithreading implementation

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a program that uses the Android adb logcat (which outputs in realtime) which outputs this to a multiline wxpython GUI box. However at the same time, I wish the user to be able to click on the window and use a "search" functionality to search through the output for a string.

I so far have the adb logcat stdout functionality to the progress box working, but when I attempt to click on the window it freezes and crashes, I am guessing this is due to being only able to do 1 thing at a time?

I have read some tutorials and plan to have a go implementing it, however I just wondered if this was the correct idea to achieve my goal?

Thanks

```
self.progressBox = wx.TextCtrl(panelLog, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)

def logcat(self,e):
    stdout = self.parent.deviceExists()
    exists = self.parent.exactMatch(stdout, "device")
    if "device" in str(exists):
        params = [toolsDir + "\\adb.exe", "logcat"]
        p = Popen(params, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
        for line in p.stdout:
            self.progressBox.AppendText(line)
```

P.S if you are a multithreading guru, and wish to give me a hand at implementing it, I won't say no.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you have here is a LongRunningTask, see the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) for some solutions. My favorite is "Easiest Implementation Ever", because is uses `wx.CallAfter` for communicating back from a thread to your main/GUI thread. You also will find some STDOUT redirection and you should be good to go.